# Counting and deleting shapes in loop

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a problem with deleting tables from all slides in a presentation.

At first the program is counting how much shapes are on the slide.
If the shape is a table delete it.

An error appears. 5 shapes are counted at the beginning. Later only 3 left because 2 tables were got deleted. I dont understand why. n_shapes is counting the shapes before the loop but I think Powerpoint is changing it dynamic.

Anyone an idea how to fix it?

```
Sub tab_del()

Dim n_shapes As Integer
Dim shape_count As Integer

Dim n_slides As Integer
Dim slide_count As Integer: slide_count = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count



For n_slides = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(n_slides).Shapes
        n_shapes = .Count
        For shape_count = 1 To n_shapes
            If .Item(shape_count).Type = msoTable Then .Item(shape_count).Delete
        Next shape_count
    
    End With

Next n_slides

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: When deleting item from a collection, it is generally best to loop backwards. Try `For shape_count = n_shapes To 1 Step - 1`

Comment: Thanks. Didnt know this command. It works fine now :)

Comment: Just to expand on the reason - When you delete an item from the collection, the rest of the items after the deleted item will have their index moved up by 1 and thus the error occurs as the collection-after-deletion has 1 item less but the loop is still going on the original collection size.